# Can't add 'at sign' on View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I need to add '@' sign in a HTML link in MVC. It should seem like that  : 
`<a href="www.twitter.com/"+@item.UserName>"@"@item.UserName </a>` 
(I didn't write wrong. One @ sign for the string one @ sign for get the model username  ) 
 I am new at C#/MVC so if anybody help me to do this link I will be so glad. Thank you so much

Comment: Use double `@` like this `@@`

Comment: You dont need the "+" either....

Comment: @S.Akbari thank i will try but part of href doesnt work too, even i can get usernames link href looks like username is null

Comment: @Wheels73 thanks i will try

Comment: @S.Akbari unfortunately it doesnt work . I try twice @@ and @ @ with space

Comment: below line should work                                                                               <a href="www.twitter.com/@item.UserName">@@item.UserName </a>

Comment: @kamalaenderson. try this <a href="www.twitter.com/"@item.UserName>&#64; @item.UserName</a>  . use &#64; to render @ symbol .

Comment: @kamalaenderson - Hi. I've posted an answer that does what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should work. You need to construct the url for the hyperlink and include the user name from the model so you get `http://www.twitter.com/UserName1`

Then you need to render the link text itself so you see the username on screen.

I've tested this with the below using a field called Username on my model. It should do what you need.

```
 <a href="http://www.twitter.com/@Model.Username">@@@Model.Username</a>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: can you edit the answer the link looks like '@username'  so the double @ siqgn betweetn a tags if you know of course. thanks

Comment: @kamalaenderson - Sorry.. i missed that bit :) all done